# How to trim text displayed in a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have my own combobox (autocompleteCombobox) where I would like to see only 35 characters of the selectedItem, but with a tooltip that show the full name.

The user control code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ComboboxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShownName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="Combobox" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
              IsEditable="True" TextSearch.Text="ShownName"
              IsTextSearchEnabled="True" DisplayMemberPath="ShownName"
              ToolTip="{Binding SelectedItem.ShownName,ElementName=autoComplete}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource,ElementName=autoComplete}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=autoComplete}"
              Style="{StaticResource ComboboxStyle}">
        <ComboBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Enter"
                        Command="{Binding Path=SelectItemCommand, ElementName=autoComplete}"
                        CommandParameter="ShownName"/>
        </ComboBox.InputBindings>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

And inside the cs file of the autocompletecombobox:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxTextLengthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MaxTextLength",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(ComboBoxAutoComplete),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(35));
        public int MaxTextLength
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(MaxTextLengthProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(MaxTextLengthProperty, value);
                LimitTextInCombobox();
            }
        }

        private void LimitTextInCombobox()
        {
            Combobox.Text = Combobox.Text.Substring(0, MaxTextLength);   
        }
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: What about creating a new `IValueConverter` instead of a new `DependecyProperty` to limit the text?

Comment: Can you show me how it works?

Comment: I'm trying but if you convert the text to limit it, the tooltip is limited too...

Comment: What is the `TextSearch` property of your ComboBox?

Comment: Is an option to make a combobox as autocomplete combobox... for example, you start to write A in the combobox and it searchs into the ShownName property of the item all the items started with A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trimming the text to a certain number of characters you could let WPF trim it for you with respect to the visual width of the text, which probably would look better. If that is an option for you, you could look into the [`TextBlock.TextTrimming`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming(v=vs.110).aspx)-property.

Comment: @Krom You can give it an ItemTemplate that does have one.

Comment: @Krom Using your own template will have no effect at all on any of that. If you need help writing the template I can show you how.

Comment: It could be usefull, but if I put the textTrimming in the textblock, then all the items will be trimmed, and I only want to trim the item that is shown in the combobox as the "selected", not the other elements of the list (when the list is drop-down, the items must have their normal length)

Comment: @EdPlunkett yep, it could be helpfull... I'm trying your option but works with the list when the items are drop-down, with the selected item that it's shown doesn't work...

Comment: The problem with my code is that if I want to have the SearchText option, it must be editable, and if it's editable, the texttrimming doesn't work for the selected item.

Comment: @Krom Ahhh, I see.

Answer (score 1):

you can use converter

```
    [ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(string))]
public class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string str = value.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            if (str.Length >= 35)
            {
                return str.Substring(0, 35);
            }
            else
            {
                return str;
            }

        }

    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

and in Xaml

```
    <Windows.Resources>
    <dict:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StringFormatConverter"/>
</Windows.Resources>

<UserControl.Resources>
<Style x:Key="ComboboxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShowName, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: but with this solution, all the items will be trimmed... I only want the shown, but the tooltip must show the full name

Answer (score 1):

The setter of a CLR wrapper for a dependency property should always *only* call the `SetValue` method to set the value of the dependency property. Nothing else:

```
public int MaxTextLength
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(MaxTextLengthProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(MaxTextLengthProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Also, you want to keep the original value to be able to display it in the tooltip anyway.

Using a converter as suggested by @Alematt seems like a good option. Just modify the `ItemTemplate` slightly:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:Converter x:Key="converter" />
    <Style x:Key="ComboboxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShownName, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And create a converter class:

```
public class Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string shownName = value as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(shownName) && shownName.Length > 35)
            return shownName.Substring(0, 35) +  "...";

        return value;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And keep the `Tooltip` as it is:

```
ToolTip="{Binding SelectedItem.ShownName, ElementName=autoComplete}"
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it trim the strings, but only with the combobox is dropdown :D I would like to trim the shown value in the combobox (the selected item)

Comment: Then you should set the IsEditable property to false.

Comment: I arrived to the same conclusion... I really don't find any way to do it with the textsearch option and the enabled option...

Comment: You can't really control how the ComboBox control sets the Text of the editable TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that just pass the SelectedItem to your converter like so:

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmb">
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multi}">
                                        <Binding Path="."/>
                                        <Binding Path="SelectedItem" ElementName="cmb"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
        <ComboBox.Items>
            <sys:String>Very long string 1</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Very long string 2</sys:String>
        </ComboBox.Items>
    </ComboBox>
```

Then use your converter like so:

```
class MultiValConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] != null && values[1] != null)
        {
            if (values[0].ToString() == values[1].ToString())
            {
                return "...";//put your logic here i.e. substring(0,30);
            }
        }
        return values[0];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and you would reference the converter like this:

```
<locals:MultiValConverter x:Key="multi"/>
```